# trouble with emacs-clang-complete-async

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I've been trying to set up [emacs-clang-complete-async](https://github.com/Golevka/emacs-clang-complete-async). I've compiled the clang-complete binary and don't get any errors in emacs, but the auto-complete feature doesn't seem to be working.

This is what I have in my .emacs:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/")
(require 'auto-complete-clang-async)

(defun ac-cc-mode-setup ()
  (setq ac-clang-complete-executable "~/.emacs.d/clang-complete")
  (setq ac-sources '(ac-source-clang-async))
  (ac-clang-launch-completion-process)
)
(defun ac-common-setup ()
  ())
(defun my-ac-config ()
  (add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'ac-cc-mode-setup)
  (add-hook 'auto-complete-mode-hook 'ac-common-setup)
  (global-auto-complete-mode t))

(my-ac-config)
```

Comment: Could you check where `clang-complete` is ? Is it into `~/.emacs.d` ? You should change `ac-clang-complete-executable` if `clang-complete` is into different place.

Comment: yeah both clang-complete and the .el are in that directory

Comment: Have you any success with it? I have exactly the same problem. I have compiled src successfully but when I open .cpp file with Emacs autocomplete don't work...

Comment: Not really. I ended up switching to company mode. It's a bit slow, but its clang completion mode worked out of the box.